# Get unexpected results date when convert long to date

Tags: android

i got this time: 1365443145000

i need to get Sensible date `(dd/MM/yyyy)`

i try : `Date d = new Date(1365443145000L * 1000);`

but i got: `45239-03-04`

Instead of Correct result is: `08/04/2013 20:45`

Comment: What's the units for the time you're starting with? Hours? Seconds? Milliseconds? The `Date(Long)` constructor expects milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont' multiply with 1000 as you are getting the time in Milliseconds. You can convert date in milliseconds to Date by using the below code, one by using `Date` constructor and second by using `Calendar`

call it like this

```
Date d=new Date(1365443145000L);
    System.out.println(d.toString());
```

**output:**
Mon Apr 08 17:45:45 UTC 2013

Check this link

http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/17928

**Edit:**

To convert required format use this code

```
 Calendar caldate=Calendar.getInstance();
    caldate.setTimeInMillis(1365443145000L);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm");
    String strdate=sdf.format(caldate.getTime());
    System.out.println(strdate);
```